# How do I send stdout to the clipboard?

Tags: command-line, stdout, clipboard

Is there functionality in Unix that allows for the following:

```
echo "Some Text" | copy-to-clipboard
```

Comment: you must mean stdout?

Comment: it really depends on which side of the pipe your standing on :P to the command that sends it to the clipboard, its `stdin`.

Comment: People who have used Unix for a long time will tell you it's better to write `<longTextFile straightToClipboard`.  It's the same as `cat longTextFile straightToClipboard`, but doesn't require running `cat`.  Just an observation.  Feel free to ignore it.  See [The Useless Use of Cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) for some background and examples if you're interested.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are a couple tools capable of writing to the clipboard; I use [`xsel`](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/). It takes flags to write to the primary X selection (`-p`), secondary selection (`-s`), or clipboard (`-b`). Passing it `-i` will tell it to read from stdin, so you want:

```
$ echo "Some Text" | xsel -i -b
```

Comment: Another one is xclip; it accepts from stdin by default. I only use it because it's the first such tool that I learned of.

Comment: @Shawn Post it as a separate answer :)

Comment: I think `-i` is not required in this case: `man xsel` 1.2.0 says: `and the selection is set from standard input if standard input is not a terminal (tty)`

Comment: xsel didn't work for me (I don't know why), but xclip (per other answers) did.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek There is neither a `xsel` nor a `xclip` on RedHat/CentOS7. Do you know of another tool available on CentOS7 ?

Answer (score 18):

Using `xclip`, as @Nicolas suggested, if you want to later paste the contents of the clipboard, such as using Ctrl+V, you can use it this way:

```
$ echo "Some Text" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: Not trying to revive an old question, but if you're lazy then `echo "Some Text" | xclip -sel c` works too.

Answer (score 9):

you can use [xsel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/)

```
xsel < file
```

Comment: The question is: Which clipboard? Linux X server has 3 (generally, only 2 are used)...  xsel uses the PRIMARY clipboard by default.. The PRIMARY clipboard kicks in automatically **every time** you simply select soemthing. You paste if by pressing the center mouse button.. The Ctrl+C / Crtr+V type clipboard is called the CLIPBOARD clipboard :).. so if you want to use the Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V clipboard with 'xsel', the command is: `xsel -ib <file-long-or-short` ("Look ma, no cat!" :) ... or if you like `<file-long-or-short xsel -ib` .. -i is default. -b is for the Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V type of *clipBoard*

Comment: gnome-terminal. Edited. @jamespo - this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: works for me on gnome-terminal in ubuntu 10.04 using the xsel in the repo (paste with middle button)

Comment: This should have been a comment to Michael Mrozek's answer.

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS X there are the lovely `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands which are very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

`xclip` is a good way to go as answered by @Nicolas Raoul but when piping anything containing a newline to the clipboard, such as `pwd`, the newline is also copied. In some situations it may be desired, but mostly one doesn't want the newline.

The solution is either:

`echo -n $(pwd) | xclip -selection clipboard`

(the `-n` removes the newline from the echoed argument)

or:

`printf %s $(pwd) | xclip -selection clipboard`

The `""` around `$(pwd)` may be required but it works with and without on ubuntu with bash.

Answer (score 1):

In Wayland, this can be done with [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard):

```
$ echo "hello" | wl-copy
```

Similarly, the clipboard can be returned as follows:

```
$ wl-paste
hello
```

Comment: your solution is the only one working on my chromebook. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably `xclip`:

```
$ echo "Some Text" | xclip
```

Then paste using your mouse's middle button.

Like `xsel`, it is usually not installed by default, so you might need to install it (`sudo apt-get install xclip` on Debian/Ubuntu).

Comment: `xclip` requires the `-selection clipboard` option. The default selection per its man page is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin (and hence also MSYS2 and Git Bash) has the /dev/clipboard device for accessing the Windows clipboard, so input/output can simply be redirected there.