# How to copy a long textfile to clipboard on gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I send stdin to the clipboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-i-send-stdin-to-the-clipboard)

What's the best way to copy a long text file to keyboard? I'm imagining something like:

```
cat longTextFile | straightToClipboard
```