# Is there a limit for the read command?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, read, limit

I'm trying to write a bash script that will let me save a backup code (lots of numbers) in a file. I've finished the script but it's only letting me to save 4096 digits of the code.

I tried to do this:

```
# Ask for backup code
read -p "Backup code:" backupcode
# Check backup code length
l="${#backupcode}"
m=4096
if (( l > m )); then
    echo -e "${RED}ERROR:${NC} Backup is too large! The limit is 4096 digits."
else
    # Save backup code in the file
    echo $backupcode > "${path[$i]}"
fi
```

I think this didn't detect that the backup was too large. So, I think there's something with read command.

If there's a limit in `read`, are there any alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no limit for the `read` command itself. But there's a limit for how much you can type on a single line in the terminal. To see this, try running the command `wc -c` and typing a very long line. You'll hit that same limit at 4096 bytes.

To input more than the limit, either arrange to make the code multi-line with each line being short enough, or input it in some other way than directly reading from the terminal in [cooked mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_mode).

If you enable readline, bash reads characters one by one, and there's no limit to the line length other than available memory.

```
read -e -p "Backup code:" backupcode
```

However, reading such a long input from the terminal is a very bad user interface. A user isn't going to sit there and type thousands of characters. Instead, read input [from the clipboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113775/getting-the-value-of-the-clipboard) or from a file.

Comment: Thank you. I'm saving the backup from the clipboard so that should be much easier.

Comment: I have encountered limit of 4095 characters when **reading from a file:** `while read -r line ; do` ... `printf %s\\n "$line" >>"$failed_file"` --- this writes the line truncated to 4095 characters ... `done < "$in_file"`. `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`