# Print the system clipboard content in bash

Tags: bash, xorg, clipboard

There is a way to put some command output to system clipboard via `xclip`.

```
some-command | xclip -selection clipboard
```

I'd like to perform a reverse task - Print system clipboard to terminal. How it can be done?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but definetly related, is [this question and especially the answers given](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3892/19575)

Answer (score 12):

According to the manpage the `-o` option to `xclip` shoves data in the opposite direction:

```
   -i, -in
          read text into X selection from standard input or files (default)

   -o, -out
          prints the selection to standard out (generally for piping to a file or program)
```

In your above command, the `-i` is being assumed.

Answer (score 6):

Another choice is the `xsel` program:

> ```
> By default, this program outputs the selection without modification  if
>    both  standard  input  and standard output are terminals (ttys). Other‐
>    wise, the current selection is output if standard output is not a  ter‐
>    minal  (tty),  and the selection is set from standard input if standard
>    input is not a terminal (tty). If any input or output options are given
>    then the program behaves only in the requested mode.
> ```

So, just copy something to the clipboard and run `xsel` to print it to the terminal. You can have a read through `man xsel` for more advanced options like which clipboard should be used etc.

Comment: To simplify things ... this is what I do: `alias pbcopy='xsel --clipboard --input';
alias pbpaste='xsel --clipboard --output'
` I chose the names to match the MacOS commands.