# How can I copy the output of a command in the terminal to my clipboard?

Tags: io-redirection, clipboard

I have a script that operates on enormous files and outputs an enormous amount of content (almost 7000 lines). I need to copy the output of this to my clipboard so I can then paste it into paste2.org and make a paste. Is there a way for me to directly copy the output to my clipboard? Some operation like that of redirection for the clipboard?

Comment: @Gilles That question is the other way around, i.e. paste, not copy. This one is about copying: [How do I send stdin to the clipboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-i-send-stdin-to-the-clipboard).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tools `xsel` or `xclip` to translate from X clipboard to stdin/stdout on a terminal. If these aren't installed, they're usually available through your distro's package manager. See the man page for the relevant tool to get details on invocation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use file redirection to save standard out to a temporary file such as `/tmp/o`

   $ script.sh > /tmp/o
2. Open browser such as Firefox/Iceweasel, to address: `/tmp/o`
3. *Now* select all, copy and paste to Pastebin.org