# can i use .bash_profile to create an alias which copies text from a file?

Tags: terminal, osx

I have a long string of text saved in a file that I want to easily copy to clipboard using Os X 10.11 terminal

Comment: Create an [Automator task for a Shell Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281372/executing-shell-scripts-from-the-os-x-dock) that runs `pbcopy < name-of-template-file`. Then map that to a key.

Answer (score 0):

```
pbcopy < myfile.txt
```

or

```
cat myfile.txt | pbcopy
```

See `man pbcopy` and `man pbpaste`.

(This is specific to Mac OS X; for Linux there are [other similar commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3892/135943).)