# How to use clipboard data in bash script?

Tags: bash, clipboard

I very often use a simple curl command to get IP addresses details.
curl ipinfo.io/111.222.333.444

Almost everytime I got the IP address in the clipboard

Is there a way to use a bash variable to automatically have the clipboard value use for IP address?

Ideally I'd like to create an alias 
Alias iploc = 'curl ipinfo.io/{pbcopy}'

So then each time I copy an ip address in clipboard I can just type "iploc" in terminal and get the result. 
l

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`xsel`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) to access the clipboard

```
iploc='curl ipinfo.io/$(xsel -o)'
```

see also [Pipe to/from the clipboard in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-the-clipboard-in-bash-script) and [How do I send stdin to the clipboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-i-send-stdin-to-the-clipboard)

Comment: Thanks Morris. I realised that I did not mention I was on MacOS. I believe xsel is Linux only. I did some research and pbpaste seems to be the equivalent for MacOS. 
Created that alias: alias iploc='curl ipinfo.io/$(pbpaste)'

Works like a charm. 

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.